# Command Prompt like Windows

Tags: command-line

Does Ubuntu have a command prompt like Windows and if so where do I find it to display the directory tree

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, just click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! **;-)** If there are multiple answers that solve your problem please pick the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a terminal, you can open it in your Desktop Environment (windowed terminal) by calling <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or open the `gnome-terminal` software.

There's also the integrated console, you can access by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but you'll need to prove your identity.

For further information about the terminal, you can check the [official wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal).

---

As for your secondary question, the linux equivalent of `dir` (Windows) is `ls`. To get help on using it, type:

```
ls --help
```

You can also use `man ls` for the complete manual.

Along with that command, you might find useful the `cd` command, with for example `cd ..` to get higher in the tree, and `cd <mydirectory>` to enter a subdirectory.

Comment: I don't think `ls` is what they want, `tree` will show a dir tree, `ls` just lists folder contents and not in a tree.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does, it's called `Terminal` (`gnome-terminal` most likely). You can open it by searching for that name in the dash or by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

You can also go into another TTY (your graphical session is running in one of them, probably number `7`), to access them press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Fi</kbd> (replace the `i` with whatever number you like, these are the function keys, so for your graphical system that would be <kbd>F7</kbd>).

---

- If you want a tree of the directory and all of its sub-directories then I would suggest a tool called `tree`, it is not installed by default though so you will have to install it in Terminal with the command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install tree
  ```

  Then it can be run with `tree` and you can find more information about how to use it in its manual page:

  ```
  man tree
  ```
- If you just want to list the contents of a directory then the pre-installed tool `ls` should do the trick for you (just run it with that). It also has a `man` page accessed in the same way as with `tree`.